# Why can't I run dual monitors in widescreen mode at the same time?

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, monitor

I have a widescreen laptop, and a Viewsonic widescreen monitor. For some reason, I cannot have both of them running in widescreen mode at the same.

In other words, if I have my Laptop in widescreen, then I cannot set my Viewsonic in widescreen, and vice versa. That tells me that it is not the Viewsonic, and it is not VGA port in the back of my laptop that is the problem, tt has got to be a setting somewhere. Any idea?

For my system specs, I am running Ubuntu 11.10 x64
my Video Card is an ATI Technologies Inc RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10].

Here is what happens when I try to setup both monitors. When I go to: System Settings\Display & set my Laptop to 1280x800 (16:10) & set my View Sonic to 1440x900 (16:10), I don't think I get an error (where would I look), all I see is both screens get fuzzy & stay fuzzy for 30 seconds till the application reverts back to the previous settings.

Comment: does it give you an error?

Comment: what video card are you using ? Is the resolution of the monitors the same ?

Comment: To jrg & bodhi.zazen - Thank you both for your questions. I updated the post to reflect my answers.

Comment: Are you running in mirror mode or are you having them cover two areas of a virtual desktop? If the latter are you trying to run them side-by-side with Unity 3d?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!